# IIS7 Replication Configuration Settings

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to set up a web farm where IIS configuration settings are replicated between the 2 servers.  I do not want to use a shared configuration as this presents another point of failure.  I have both machines (WWW1 and WWW2) set up to use a configuration file on D:\IISConfig.  With this done I  manually copy the configruation files from WWW1 to WWW2 and WWW2 works just fine.  I then took it one step further and added file replication to automatically push any changes on WWW1 to WWW2.  Then I added an App Pool to WWW1.  At this point I can also browse my website with no issues on WWW1.  When I went to IIS7 on WWW2 , I could see the new app pool . . .- GREAT.  I tried to browse the website on WWW2 and I get an error that shuts down the DefaultAppPool:

The Module DLL c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll failed to load.  The data in this error . . .

Any ideas why this might be occuing and how to get arround it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Belongs on Serverfault.com?

I think that when you use the configuation file and path, it is pretty much the same as using a shared configuration.

I would check that you have exactly the same modules loaded as it sounds to me like you have a security module on one web server that is not on the other, the config file is telling it to load which is causing the server to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the shared configuration instead.

In my Windows 2008 cluster, I have IIS set to use the shared configuration where the configuration folder is set to a folder on the local server.  Then I have that folder set up as a DFS share.  That way the IIS changes are automatically replicated in the cluster and the server's don't have to talk to a remote server to get the config files.  This has been working great for years.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the actual issue here is that it failed to load an authentication module.

`authsspi.dll` is provided by adding 'Basic Authentication' as part of the Web Server role in Windows Server. I can see this being an issue if (like me) you're accidentally using Shared Configuration across 2 or more servers that don't have an identical Role configuration for IIS.